# Omitting np.ndarray element

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I am looking for a more pleasant form of

```
data[[j for j in range(n) if i!=j], :]
```

I can't use delete as the array will be used further. Any suggestion?

Comment: *"I can't use delete as the array will be used further."*  Your code makes a copy, and `numpy.delete` makes a copy.  So what is wrong with `delete`?

Comment: What's `i` in there?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [masked array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.html).